# Flash Action Script: How would I select a video source dynamically within a flash swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I have looked at a number of tutorials where you can change the source of the flv video displayed.

e.g.

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, vid1);

function vid1(e:Event):void{
vidPlayer.source = "Testing/01.flv";
};
```

So with this if the button was clicked then it would play the video with file path "Testing/01.flv"

What I am looking to do is replace "Testing/01.flv" with a variable that would have the file path data in. So in theory the user would be able to select another video file from their computer to play.

I have previously used the code below to allow the user to select a text file from an external source. Would this be able to be adapted to my purpose?

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_OpenFile);

var fl_OpenFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();    // FileStream used to read from the file
var fl_OpenFileChooser:File = File.documentsDirectory;  // Default to the documents directory
fl_OpenFileChooser.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fl_FileOpenSelected);

// Main function for opening a file
function fl_OpenFile(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_OpenFileChooser.browseForOpen("Select a text file.");
}

// Opens a FileStream object to read the file
function fl_FileOpenSelected(event:Event):void
{
    fl_OpenFileChooser = event.target as File;
    fl_OpenFileStream = new FileStream();
    fl_OpenFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fl_FileReadHandler);

    fl_OpenFileStream.openAsync(fl_OpenFileChooser, FileMode.READ);
}

// Write data from the file to the Output Panel
function fl_FileReadHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var fileData:String = fl_OpenFileStream.readMultiByte(fl_OpenFileStream.bytesAvailable, File.systemCharset);
    // The data loaded from the file can now be used from the variable fileData.
    // This example code displays data from the file in the Output panel.
    trace(fileData);
    fl_OpenFileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Looking at your example code, you want this for AIR, right? This won't wok for Flash player.

Comment: Yep I am using AIR as it will work better for what I am doing.

Comment: I don't think you need to load and read the file in air, you simply need to path to the file, so in fl_FileOpenSelected, as soon as you assigned `fl_OpenFileChooser` you can try `vidPlayer.source = fl_OpenFileChooser.nativePath;`. Basically, you saw what file was selected in the fl_FileOpenSelected handler and just need to pass the [nativePath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#nativePath) to your player. Also have a look at [url](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#url)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks George Profenza. It was the .nativePath that I was missing. And as you say I don't need to use the whole of that code as I am not reading the file just getting the file path. So I just used the first part of the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to George Profenzas' comment here is my solution to the problem.

With this code I now have a working application that the user can select the video source in.

So on the first frame I have two buttons one that brings up a file select window (`movieClip_1`) and one that moves to the next frame (`movieClip_2`)

```
stop()

import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_OpenFile);

var fl_OpenFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();    // FileStream used to read from the file
var fl_OpenFileChooser:File = File.documentsDirectory;  // Default to the documents directory
fl_OpenFileChooser.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fl_FileOpenSelected);

// Main function for opening a file
function fl_OpenFile(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_OpenFileChooser.browseForOpen("Select a video file.");

}

// Opens a FileStream object to read the file
function fl_FileOpenSelected(event:Event):void
{
videopath = fl_OpenFileChooser.nativePath;
}


/* Click to Go to Next Frame and Stop
Clicking on the specified symbol instance moves the playhead to the next frame and stops the movie.
*/

movieClip_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

On the second frame I have this code:

```
vidPlayer.source = videopath ;
```

Where `vidPlayer` is the instance of the flvplayer component.

Finally here is the actionscript class file code for the variable `videopath`

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.setInterval;
    import flash.utils.clearInterval;
    import flash.events.VideoEvent;
    import fl.video.*;

    public class videotest extends MovieClip {
        public var videopath:String; 


        public function videotest() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}
```

It's important that the variable videopath is set to a string otherwise the link won't work.

I am still learning so this may not be the best way to do it or the best coding practice but it works and I can't find a better way of doing it so there you go.